# What's "function_exists" in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Im very new to WordPress. I was going through Smooth Slider WP Plugin and saw

```
if ( function_exists( 'get_smooth_slider_category' ) ) { get_smooth_slider_category('Uncategorized'); }
```

This pretty much gives what I wanted, but not quite. This pulls all the content in the category and what Im after is just the image URL.

My question is whats "function_exists" in wordpress? and I checked get_smooth_slider_category in functions.php file but couldnt find any. Can someone please explain how function_exists works?

Comment: [Wordpress Codex - Hiding Plugins When Deactivated](http://codex.wordpress.org/Managing_Plugins#Hiding_Plugins_When_Deactivated)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[function_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) is a PHP function, not limited to WordPress.

From the manual "Checks the list of defined functions, both built-in (internal) and user-defined, for function_name."

It returns true or false on whether or not the function exists. So you can either create a new function before it that does something slightly different, or prevent an error if it doesn't exist (normally because the required file hasn't been included).

Answer (score 1):

This is a [PHP function](http://php.net/function-exists) that checks if the passed in name matches any defined functions (either internal, or user defined).

It is a way to check if a function is "available" before calling it.