# WooCommerce products shortcode outputs class="columns-x" twice

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode, storefront

Just a vanilla call to product-category shortcode in `functions.php` is confusing me.

I'm trying to get a `columns-3` of text sitting next to a `columns-9` of products.

My code:

```php
<div class="content">
  <div class="columns-3">
    <?php $home_kit = get_term(30, 'product_cat', ARRAY_A); ?>
    <h2 class="section-title"><?php echo $home_kit['name']; ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $home_kit['description']; ?></p>
    <a href=" <?php echo get_category_link($home_kit['term_id']); ?>">All Products &raquo;</a>
  </div>
  <?php echo do_shortcode('[product_category category="home-kits" per_page="3" orderby="price" order="desc" columns="9"]'); ?>
</div>
```

The shortcode generates:

```html
<div class="homepage-home-kit-category">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="columns-3">
     <h2...</h2>
     <p>...</p>
     <a ...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="woocommerce columns-9 ">
      <ul class="products columns-9">
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Note the repeat of the `columns-9` on both the generated `<div>` and `<ul>`.

If both the `<div>` and `<ul>` have class `columns-9` then I get 3/4 of the available 3/4.

Surely the class `columns-9` only needs to be on either the WooComerce `<div>` or the `<ul>`.

How can I remove this addition from the `<ul>` element?

I am gratefull for the answers I received which are all valid and work well.
I suppose my underlying problem is that I cannot see the usefulness of the product_category shortcode as it does not obey the columns parameter faithfully.
Am I alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options to remove/modify the `columns-9` class from the `<ul>` element

**Solution 1** - Through the use of a filter hook.

```php
function filter_woocommerce_product_loop_start( $loop_start ) {
    // New output
    $loop_start = '<ul class="products">';
    
    return $loop_start;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_loop_start', 'filter_woocommerce_product_loop_start', 10, 1 );
```

---

**Solution 2** - Overwriting the template file.

You could overwrite the [templates/loop/loop-start.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/templates/loop/loop-start.php) template file

- This template can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php.`

Replace

```php
<ul class="products columns-<?php echo esc_attr( wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' ) ); ?>">
```

With

```php
<ul class="products">
```

---

**Solution 3** - overwriting the existing function.

Since `woocommerce_product_loop_start` uses `function_exits`, see: [includes/wc-template-functions.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1110-L1134) on line 1110-1134 @version 2.5.0

More info: [What's "function_exists" in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12128580/11987538)

```php
/**
 * Output the start of a product loop. By default this is a UL.
 *
 * @param bool $echo Should echo?.
 * @return string
 */
function woocommerce_product_loop_start( $echo = true ) {
    $loop_start = '<ul class="products">';

    if ( $echo ) {
        // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
        echo $loop_start;
    } else {
        return $loop_start;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. Lots to try and lots to learn from. And I'm still bemused by the repeated classes. I've seen other code and the columns class is only on the woocommerce div. So something changed? Again, apart from 12/12 any other columns=x in the do_shortcode method must create a fraction of a fraction of the grid?

Comment: _"I've seen other code and the columns class is only on the woocommerce div"_. As I mentioned, this is default. Many themes will therefore overwrite the template files or change the output via hooks. Another option is to take this into account when assigning CSS. One option has its advantages over the other, but mostly depends on personal preference. 
It also depends on whether you write a theme from 0 yourself or adapt an existing theme. Where you then have to take into account what the theme author has already applied.

Comment: My theme is a child of generic storefront with generic WooCommerce plug. But you've sent me on a path. Thanks.