# How to add HTML in "No products were found matching your selection" WooCommerce message

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

In WooCommerce, The "No products were found matching your selection." text appears when no products are found in the loop.

However, I want to add HTML in the text, so I use the [gettext](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext/) filter hook. Via `str_ireplace` I can easily overwrite the text:

```php
function change_empty_category_text($translated) {
   $translated = str_ireplace ('No products were found matching your selection.', 'sorry! we are not delivering products from this category to you pin code at the moment.', $translated);
   return $translated;
 }
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_empty_category_text' );
```

---

However, when I want to add HTML in this text:

```php
function change_empty_category_text($translated) {
   $translated = str_ireplace ('No products were found matching your selection.', 'sorry! we are not delivering products from this category to you pin code at the moment.\r\nplease visit the following categories instead\r\n<a href = 'www.example.com/category1'>category 1</a>\r\n<a href = 'www.example.com/category2'>category 2</a>\r\n<a href = 'www.example.com/category3'>category 3</a>', $translated);
   return $translated;
 }
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_empty_category_text' );
```

It has no result. Instead, I am getting the same exact text as written in the replacement.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

The text you want to adjust can be found in [templates/loop/no-products-found.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/0a857088f994def1aca6f3feb3e4a4af964b225f/templates/loop/no-products-found.php), so you could overwrite the template file
versus using the `gettext` filter hook, since this hook is executed multiple times on every page load.

However, there is another option. Since `wc_no_products_found` uses `function_exits`, see: [/includes/wc-template-functions.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/0a857088f994def1aca6f3feb3e4a4af964b225f/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L3254-L3262) on line 3254-3262 @version 2.5.0

```php
if ( ! function_exists( 'wc_no_products_found' ) ) {

    /**
     * Handles the loop when no products were found/no product exist.
     */
    function wc_no_products_found() {
        wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' );
    }
}
```

More info: [What's "function_exists" in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128558/whats-function-exists-in-wordpress/12128580#12128580)

---

So instead of using the existing template file, which is called via `wc_get_template()` in the function, we are going to rewrite the function with our own function.

So you get:

```php
function wc_no_products_found() {
    echo '<p class="woocommerce-info" style="display:block;">' . 
        __( 'Sorry! we are not delivering products from this category to you pin code at the moment.<br>Please visit the following categories instead', 'woocommerce' ) 
        . '<br><a href ="www.example.com/category2">category 2</a><br><a href="www.example.com/category3">category 3</a></p>';
}
```

As you can see the output is fully customizable to your needs. CSS adjustments may be required, since this is theme dependent.

Code goes in `functions.php` file of your active child theme (or active theme).